# init() not running in new package

Tags: go

I haven't used Go in a while and I'm just starting to work on an old project again.

I have `init()` functions in a number of the packages and they work fine. However I've just created a new package and added an `init()` function but it won't run during initialization like the others. If I put the `init()` function in an previously existing package it runs fine...

I believe this is a simple problem but I can't for the life of me figure it out. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Need more details to form a definitive answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you main program does not import your new package at all... its `init()` function would not be called.

If you just want an imported package's `init()` function to be executed, and don't want to use package's other content, you should modify `import "foo"` to `import _ "foo"`.

See [`init` function](https://nanxiao.gitbooks.io/golang-101-hacks/content/posts/init-function.html) (and its [full documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17733407/6309) in [program execution](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)).

Comment: That was it. Thanks!